# last element not getting insert in list - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to append a successive lists like this:

```
result(R) :- append(A,B,C), append(C,D,E), append(E,F,R).
```

> PS: A,B,D and F are results (lists) of another predicates in the same rule result(R). 
>   for example: A is like `[1,2]`

My goal is to get one list.

Example: A is [1,2] and B is [3,4], D is [5] and F is [6,7] and R will be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

But when I execute this code with `trace.` I get the following error:

```
Fail: (19) append([12|13], 19, _G23439) ? creep
```

The last element did not append! This is append's predicate:

```
appende([], List, List).
appende([Head|Tail], List, [Head|Rest]) :-appende(Tail, List, Rest).
```

(Edit for Kate):

This is the rule:

```
s1(X,Y) :-
   ( ws(X,R) ; 1 is A ),
   ( ai(X,S) ; 1 is B ),
   ( py(X,T) ; 1 is C ),
   ( stat(X,U) ; 1 is D ),
   ( bdav(X,V) ; 1 is E ),
   ( ang(X,W) ; 1 is F ),
   appende(R,S,RS),
   appende(RS,T,RST),
   appende(RST,U,RSTU),
   append‌e(RSTU,V,RSTUV),
   appe‌​nde([],RSTUV,RSTUVS)‌​,
   appende(RSTUVS,[W],Final),
   append([],Final,Y),
   avg(Y,M),
   maplist(=<(10),[M]),
   somme([A,B,C,D,E,F],So),
   maplist(>=(1),[So]).
```

Append is :

```
append([], List, List).
append([Head|Tail], List, [Head|Rest]) :-
   append(Tail, List, Rest).
```

The goal is the get `Final` list like that: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and store it in Y

Comment: But `append` expects **two lists**, not a list and an element... Please provide the full query...

Comment: The way you have written your rule for `result(R)`, `A`, `B`,  and `F` are *singleton* meaning they only appear once. How does `A` become `[1, 2]` in this context?